# Is there a way to execute update of the updatepanel before the other function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I'm programming an asp.net website so I want on a dropdownlist textchanged to update the panel and execute a function which takes the data from the DB and update the panel with this data all this things in js, But my panel update everytime that's good but with the relevant information only once at the first time.

The second time the data are filled before the panel update so when it update it's empty.

```
 protected void DropDownList1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentPickArea = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;


            UpdatePanel4.Update();


            if (currentPickArea != DROPLIST_PICK_AREA_START_TEXT)
            {

                LoadPickPlacesBySelectedPickArea();
                if (currentPickArea == "QA_Zone")
                {
                    component.processGetLocationByLocationId(currentPickArea);
                }
            }


        }
```

Initial view
[image: Initial view]

View with panel updated correctly with right information
[image: View with panel updated correctly with right information]

View when i tried to make a second update so without information get from database because the panel update after changes on the database
[image: View when i tried to make a second update so without information get from database because the panel update after changes on the database]

I want to execute the update first when the update is done or i know it will be done before the rest i let the program continue.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what it is you're trying to acomplish based on the information provided. What are you doing with javascript? Are you databinding in c#? You would need to do your databinding first and then update the panel for this to display correctly.

Comment: I add some picture to show what expected. And No I need to do the update first and then databing in the js. In the js I just activate in the dark grey the right label but it's working only for the first textchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `TextChanged` is an internal event and should not be used. Change it to `SelectedIndexChanged` as this is the correct event to determine when the dropdown selection changes. You can also try setting the dropdown's `AutoPostBack` property to `false` and `EnableViewState` to `true`.

Comment: The problem is not with the textchanged it's with the update() it's made after all the rest. I want to make the update first.